# Filter objects by ManyToManyField Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a friends feature on my website, and I want the homescreen to be posts filtered by the users the current user follows.

Here is the relevant model

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=30)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='user_connections')
```

And the relevant view

```py
class PostViewList(HitCountDetailView,SelectRelatedMixin,ListView):
    model = Post    
    count_hit = True
    template_name = 'mainapp/list.html'
    select_related = ("user","group",)
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        # return Post.objects.filter(author__friends__friend__id=self.request.user.id)
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        select_related = ("user","group",)
        # user = self.user
        return qs.filter(Q(friend__author=self.kwargs['post.author']))
```

*note that the group in the `select_related` is there because of another unrelated feature

As you can see, I have tried to filter out posts, but it doesn't work.

I don't know what I am missing/doing wrong.

Comment: assuming you have an `author` attribute in `Post` model, which is foreign keyed to `User`, you can use `filter(author__user_connections__in=[self.request.user])`

Comment: Thanks for that man
Could you make an answer on the post so I can mark it as correct

Comment: you're welcome Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an `author` attribute in `Post` model, which is foreign keyed to `User`, you can use `filter(author__user_connections__in=[self.request.user])`
So basically this filter says: "look for the Posts that their authors have `self.request.user` in their related friend objects"